# Javascript: Regex or some other technique to control read-only input

Tags: javascript, regex, calculator

I'm in the proccess of creating 'Windows-like' calculator. I already built my calculator in *html* and set input to read-only to resemble that of Windows'. Now, I know you can control basic input by creating proper regex, but is it the case with read-only?

What I want is that I control what goes in input box by adding event listeners than updating input if conditions are met which I already did but can I restrict my code further by using regex or some other technique for proper math algorithms like  **3.55*(4/(1+1))**? I hope I'm clear about what I need.

I tried setting countless variables and control them with if/switch statements which worked in the end, but it took me around 100 lines of code which quickly became a nightmare to control, so I started from scratch and looking for alternatives, and if what I learned about JS is true, it's possible. Only pure JS and no other libraries, please. Here's my current JS code:

```
const domRef = {
  inputMain: document.getElementById('input-main'),
  inputSecondary: document.getElementById('input-secondary'),
  buttons: document.getElementById('calculator-basic').querySelectorAll('button')
}

function handleClick(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  if (target.classList.contains('expressions')) { // operands and operators
    let input = target.textContent;
    updateInputMain(input);
  }

}

function handleKeypress(event) {
  let target;
  for (let i = 0; i < domRef.buttons.length; i++) {

    if (domRef.buttons[i].textContent === event.key) {
      target = domRef.buttons[i];
      target.click();
    }

  }
}

function updateInputMain(input) {
  domRef.inputMain.value += input;
}



for (let i = 0; i < domRef.buttons.length; i++) {
  domRef.buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

document.body.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeypress);
```

Comment: Formulas with properly balanced brackets are not a regular language, therefore they can not be parsed with regular expressions (it's possible with some extensions, but I believe they're not available in the standard JS engine).

Comment: I think you might be right since I haven't found any example yet, even though I'm searching for days now.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a specialized library, e.g. [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/index.html)

Doing powerful calculations become as easy as that:

```js
math.sqrt(-4); // 2i
console.log(math.eval(3.55*(4/(1+1))));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/4.4.2/math.min.js"></script>
```

Math.js contains a function [math.parse](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#parse) to parse expressions into an expression tree. That should come handy.

Also, we can wrap parse or eval with a try-catch block to check for syntax errors:

```js
try {
  math.parse('3.55*(4/(1+1)');
}
catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/4.4.2/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I realize I'll have to deal with parsing problem in the future and math.js could be the way to do it, but what I want is to restrict readonly input field to get that 'parsable' expressions, which I did with large number of if\else\switch\case statements. What I want is another way to achieve that without making my code so messy. Here's my full code so far: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/exciting-pull